# Can't Find Bing Map SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8

Just downloaded the Bing Maps SDK for Visual Studio 2013. Now that I've done that I'm supposed to click PROJECT -> Add Reference and I'll see the SDK under Windows Extensions, but it's not there. The image below is what I get. I have no idea how to make the Bing Map SDK active. Does anyone know anything about this?

[image]

Comment: I created a new project and selected the Windows Store App template. With this project when I open "Add Reference" the Bing Map SDK is showing and I can select it. Is it not possible to add Bing Maps to a Windows Phone App?

Comment: for windows phone, its having separate API as Windows Phone 8 Maps API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone version of the Bing Maps Silverlight Control is still supported but it is deprecated and should only be kept for an existing app that you have upgraded from Windows Phone OS 7.1 to Windows Phone 8. To add Bing Maps to a Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8, you can use Bing Maps AJAX Control, Version 7.0 or the Windows Phone 8 Maps API. The Windows Phone 8 Maps API does not use Bing Maps.

for more Reference you can go here [Guide to the Windows Phone 8 Maps API](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/change-history/archived-content/maps-and-navigation/guide-to-the-wp8-maps-api.html)

Comment: The instructions on the guide you've linked to indicate that I just add a map object. My app doesn't run though. I get an error message saying Cannot create instance of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map'.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles across this the Bing Map SDK I was trying to add has been deprecated and doesn't work with WP8. I was on a wild goose chase.